# Change column value based on another column's first characters in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Have two columns **start_date** and **end_date** (strings):

Some of the rows in **end_date** are formated like 9999-12-12 i want to replace 9999 for the YYYY in **start_date**

I tried extracting the first 4 characters (got a pd.Series) for the **start_date** column and using that to replace but i cannot find a way

How it is

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-25 | 2020-12-28 |
| 2021-02-02 | **9999**-02-09 |
| 2019-02-13 | **9999**-02-15 |

How it should be

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-25 | 2020-12-28 |
| **2021**-02-02 | **2021**-02-09 |
| **2019**-02-13 | **2019**-02-15 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use `np.where`:

```
df['end_date'] = np.where(df.end_date.str[:4] == '9999', df.start_date.str[:4] + df.end_date.str[4:], df.end_date)

df
   start_date    end_date
0  2020-12-25  2020-12-28
1  2021-02-02  2021-02-09
2  2019-02-13  2019-02-15
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`:

```
df['end_date'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['end_date'].replace("9999", row['start_date'][0:4]), axis=1)
```